# unison or Rsync for session files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load-balancing, rsync

In my cheap config I am using 2x app servers and 1x DB server.

My question now is what I should use in order to sync session files between the servers for my php app?

Is unison or Rsync good here, or is there something more light?

All systems are running Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

What cms are you using? You can try Memcache or Redis for storing session, and memcached/redis instante can be installed on you DB vm

Answer (score 0):

Unison allows 2 servers only.

You can try Lsyncd + Csync2, Lsyncd + Rsync or Syncthing (btSync).

> **Lsyncd** watches a local directory trees event monitor interface. It
>   aggregates and combines events for a few seconds and then spawns one
>   (or more) process(es) to synchronize the changes.
>   Source: https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/

I'd suggest Lsyncd+Csync2 or Syncthing (btsync) because they can handle file deletions and conflicts better.